# One 'message' variable present in outside and i want to take that variable into inside of res.json

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, express, passport.js

**Login page:**

[image]

> Here in 'passport.use' function i have message variable and i want pass them into 'passport.authenticate' function, because i want pass it into controller

### api.js

```
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ name : username}, function(err, user) {
        if (!user){
            return done(null, false,{message: 'Incorrect username' });
        } 

        if(user){
            var validPassword = user.comparePassword(password);

            if(!validPassword){
                return done(null, false,{message: 'Incorrect password' });
            }
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });       
}
));



router.post('/pages/auth/login', function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (user === false) {
        console.log("login error ");
        return res.json({
            success:false,
            //message: 'Incorrect Username or Password',
        });
    } else {
        console.log("login success");
        return res.json({
            success:true,
            //message: 'Login Success',
        });
    }
})(req, res, next);
});
return router;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Angular `service` to pass message variable to controller

Comment: can i send message from node.js to angular.js using that service.

Comment: i havn't worked on node.js.But, how abt this -> If you can pass some value to html page, then simply collect it in some `ng-init` function variable and can pass it to angular controller. I did something like that when I was using Djanog with AngularJS as frontend

Comment: now message shows in the html page like ''{message: 'Incorrect password' }". But i want only "Incorrect password" like this. There is no problem with                                                                                                    return res.json({
 success:false,
 message: info,
});                                                                                                              Info variable hold full message like this "{message: 'Incorrect password' }" .

Comment: sir did u see the image i had attached?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer. I used info.message and it appears in html page. Thank you